# AWS Lambda potential alternatives to connect to RDS in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-serverless

I am using a lambda function in a VPC to connect to an RDS instance in the same VPC. I am considering removing the lambda from the VPC to massively reduce the cold-start time but I want to keep my RDS instance in the VPC.

Can anyone foresee major problems with making the lambda function use an SSH tunnel to connect to a bastion instance within the VPC and subsequently to the RDS instance? Or something similar with a VPN?

There will obviously be some over-head as the traffic has an extra 'jump' so to speak, but would it be significant enough to make this approach non-feasible? Or is the only current approach to keep the Lambda in the same VPC and try to keep and few invocations running?

I also pay for a NAT gateway so my Lambda in a VPC can access the internet. If I can get it out of the VPC by using an SSH tunnel to connect to the RDS instance it will also simplify my architecture here & reduce my operating costs.

Comment: Not sure where is your hurdle. Eventhough your Lambda is in a VPC, you should be still able to access from outside world through API Gateway. It works fine for us with a private VPC lambda, exposed to outside world through API gateway. Our cold start is not too long.

Comment: @Kannaiyan It might be worth checking out https://theburningmonk.com/2018/01/im-afraid-youre-thinking-about-aws-lambda-cold-starts-all-wrong/ 
I have moved the backend to an ECS cluster for now instead, if you have a lambda in a private VPC it will have a bad cold start for alot of users due to the fact it has to attach a network interface to the lambda function. This is an issue when you get bursts of traffic. You can use some sort of 'heartbeat' to keep a few lambda invocations running, but this does not solve the problem as most users will still get a cold start.

Answer (score 0):

Cold starts because of Lambda's in VPC are a big issue, especially when you want to use a relational database. Luckily, AWS has acknowledged this issue and there is hope on the horizon;

- Aurora Serverless now supports the Data API that allows to run SQL queries using the AWS SDK over https. This is released on Nov 20 ('18) and is in beta and only in us-east-1, but it's a start.
- During re:Invent '18 an improvement on the VPC-cold-start issue was announced (but no release date yet) in which they basically create an ENI for a group of Lambda's and have that ENI ready even if there are no Lambda's warm.